# Deploying from Visual Studio to server with only RDP-access

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console-application, remote-desktop

I am about to deploy some applications to a server which I only have Remote Desktop-access to. 
Is there any straightforward way to do this using Visual Studio? My current idea is to deploy to a local folder and the copy that folder using Remote Desktop's clipboard-access. Is there any better way?